# convert UTC to local time using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

As a response from the json I am getting the UTC timezone. I need to convert it to local time.

```
<span class="text-muted">{{trans.txnDate}}</span>
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you show how you receive it from JSON? is it in milliseconds, or string?

Comment: it is string format     pattern = "yyyy:MM:dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

Comment: If I'm doing something with time and timezones I'm always using http://momentjs.com/ and http://momentjs.com/timezone/. This lib is very comfortable.

Comment: can you get it from back end as miliseconds? or you cannot change this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT (2nd Jan 2017): Please refer @Jason's answer, it is better than this one since it uses custom filter to fix the date format - that's the more Angular way of doing it.**

---

**My original answer and edits:**

You could use the `date` filter to format the date:

```
<span class="text-muted">{{trans.txnDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z' }}</span>
```

This will output:

```
2010-10-29 09:10:23 +0530
```

(assuming `trans.txnDate = 1288323623006;`)

[See this documentation of `date` in angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). It has quite a few examples that are very helpful!

---

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, use the following to get the date as `17 oct 2014`:

```
<span class="text-muted">{{trans.txnDate | date:'dd MMM yyyy' | lowercase }}</span>
```

Check the documentation link that I mentioned above.

**EDIT2:**

In response to your other comment, use the following code. The problem is that the string that you are getting is not properly formatted so the `Date` object is not able to recognise it. I have formatted it in the controller and then passed to the view.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var dateString = "2014:10:17T18:30:00Z";
  dateString = dateString.replace(/:/, '-'); // replaces first ":" character
  dateString = dateString.replace(/:/, '-'); // replaces second ":" character
  $scope.date = new Date(dateString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{date | date:'dd MMM yyyy' | lowercase }}
</div>
```

The JS code for replacement can be improved by finding a smarter way to replace the first 2 occurrences of `:` character.

Comment: Its already returning like this "2014:10:17T18:30:00Z"      But I need something like this "17 oct 2014"

Comment: Desai But i was asking something wrong question. The json is already returning convereted local date itself "2014:10:17T18:30:00Z". In this local date format I need a format like 'dd MMM yyyy'. Is der any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 30):

I just had to solve this problem as well with dates coming from .NET Web API in the format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' (e.g. 2016-02-23T00:11:31) without the 'Z' suffix to indicate UTC time.

I created this filter that extends the angular date filter and ensures that the timezone suffix is included for UTC time.

**UTC to Local Filter:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .filter('utcToLocal', utcToLocal);

    function utcToLocal($filter) {
        return function (utcDateString, format) {
            if (!utcDateString) {
                return;
            }

            // append 'Z' to the date string to indicate UTC time if the timezone isn't already specified
            if (utcDateString.indexOf('Z') === -1 && utcDateString.indexOf('+') === -1) {
                utcDateString += 'Z';
            }

            return $filter('date')(utcDateString, format);
        };
    }
})();
```

**Example Usage:**

```
{{product.CreatedDate | utcToLocal:"dd.MM.yyyy"}}
```

Comment: utcDateString param comes in as a date object, not as a string

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  AngularJs's date filter doesn't figure out the string is UTC format, but JavaScript Date object does.  So I created a simple function in the Controller:

```
$scope.dateOf = function(utcDateStr) {
    return new Date(utcDateStr);
}
```

And then used something like:

```
{{ dateOf(trans.txnDate) | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'  }}
```

It displays the date/time in the local timezone

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Below Answer

```
{{trans.txnDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z':'+0530' }} 
//You can also set '+0000' or another UTX timezome
```

Comment: What if you are in a time zone other than India?

Comment: only replace +0530 with your UTX timezone

Comment: So, to make it generic for Global we can not use this solution??