# Convert Server Timezone to Client Browser timezone using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, timezone

I have a scenario in which I am setting a date from my local timezone and when I am getting it from server its returning in Server Time Zone, I want to convert it again to local timezone to show in the UI. I have tried multiple solutions but none of them worked for me.

I am getting this server time:

```
2017-11-16T01:00:00
```

But my actual local time for that is

```
2017-11-16T06:00:00
```

So basically my local time zone in 5 hours ahead.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602746/convert-utc-to-local-time-using-angularjs) is answer you might be looking.

Comment: The *server's* time zone is irrelevant. In most cases, you should be sending the time in terms of UTC, with a `Z` at the end to indicate like `2017-11-16T01:00:00Z`.  Then it should just work, but you didn't show how you're using it - so it's hard to say.